# Prerequisites to horizontally center an element with margin: 0 auto;

Tags: html, css

What are the minimum style declaration requirements for an element that I want to horizontally center with `margin:0 auto;`?

And the minimum requirements style declaration for the containing elment(s)?

I would like the solution to be element-type agnostic, i.e. to be working no matter if it's a `span`, `div`, `a` etc.

The solution should work in any [modern browser](http://browsehappy.com/).

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the information given there works in any given situation? I'm fully aware that there exists millions of posts about this subject, but I've been very precise about the neutral conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic class with the minimum amount of required properties (avoid using the `margin: 0 auto` short-hand so you don't unnecessarily override the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties):

```
.horizontal-center {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%; /* any value other than auto */
}
```

The only constraint on `.horizontal-center`'s parent is that it needs `display: block|inline-block` and a `width` greater or equal to `.horizontal-center`'s.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `width` too, because if there is no `width` on a block-level element, it just takes all 100% of the horizontal space.

For tags like `span` or `a`, you have to make them `display block`.

Answer (score 1):

for center horizontaly you have to specify `width` of an element and u cant not use `float` property.

Comment: What's `float` got to do with anything?